# Google map geolocation for chrome same file different server can't work

Tags: php, google-maps

I have a PHP file, I am using the google geolocation's `getCurrentPosition()` function, it can work on my localhost and get the current position at windows chrome, but it can't work when I put that file on cloud server at the same PC chrome.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As Google states on https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geolocation:

> If you see the error "The Geolocation service failed.", it means you probably did not give permission for the browser to locate you.

Chech your Chrome settings under "Settings" - "Privacy" - "Content settings".

[image: Settings]
[image: Allow geolocation]

Comment: I use the same PC and same Chrome just in a different host.

Comment: Exactly. Chrome allows or disallows geolocation for each domain independently.

Comment: I had uploaded new pictures for setting detail. I found there was different in URL field. localhost has an icon but another server was not.